# Kernel of a linear transformation $D : \mathbb{C}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}) \to \mathbb{C}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

Let $D : \mathbb{C}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}) \to \mathbb{C}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ be the function given by differentiation: $D(f) = f'$.

I've shown that $D$ is a linear transformation by using rules for derivative of a sum of two functions and derivative of a scalar (constant) multiplied by a function.

I now want to find the kernel of $D$ (if it is finite, find a basis $\mathbb{B}$ for $D$) aswell as the eigenvalues of $D$.

I interpreted $\mathbb{C}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ as the smooth functions from $D$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

I've concluded that the only thing $D$ sends to $0$ are constants. Therefore: $\ker(D) = \{ a \in \mathbb{R}\}$.  $\ker(D)$ is not finite and we cannot find a basis for $D$. Is my conclusion correct?

For the eigenvalues I would appreciate a hint.

Comment: A vector space (over characteristic 0 fields) with a nonzero element is never finite, but it can have a basis

Comment: There's a difference between *finite* and *finite-dimensional*.

Comment: To expand on the above, I think you are confusing the cardinality of the set $\ker(D)$ with its dimension

Comment: That might be the case, I read your answer and it makes sense of course, I guess I confused myself using $a \in \mathbb{R}$ thinking we have infinitely many possible elements, but ofcourse the basis can just be any constant. Thank you for clarifying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right about what the kernel is, however, is it not finite? What's wrong with the basis consisting of the constant function $f(x)=1$?

Finding the eigenvalues works the same way. The ODE 
$$
Df=\lambda f\iff f'=\lambda f
$$
might be of interest.

edit 1: Given the confusion below, the $\lambda$ I have written is meant to represent an eigenvalue in $\mathbb{R}$, *not* a matrix representing the linear transformation $D$.

edit 2: Solution. We are looking for functions $f$ which satisfy 
$$
Df=\lambda f
$$
i.e. eigenvectors with eigenvalue $\lambda$. Recalling ode, we separate and integrate or ansatz solutions 
$$
f(x)=ce^{\lambda x}
$$
Where $c$ is a constant. One may check that $Df=\lambda ce^{\lambda x}=\lambda f$ by the chain rule. This will be a valid eigenvector for any $\lambda\in \mathbb{R}$, an uncountable set of eigenvectors which is pairwise linearly independent.

Comment: I don't really see how to simplify that ODE. Must I make some sort of matrix for $f'$? Am I going to end up with a finite amount of eigenvalues here?

Comment: Is it sufficient to find a matrix $\lambda$ such that this matrix multiplied by $f$, gives $f'$? Essentially a matrix $\lambda$ that differentiates $f$? If I have a polynomial of degree $n$, wouldn't i get an $n \times n$ matrix as $\lambda$ ?

Comment: Because let's say I we have $P_2 = a+bx+cx^2$. If $T$ is a transformation that takes the derivative we get $p' = b+2cx$. I can now set up a matrix that sends $a$ to $0$, $b$ to $1$ and $c$ to $2$. So if we multiplty the general basis for $P_2 = [1, x, x^2]$ with that matrix we would get $[0, 1,  2x]$. But if we allow all kinds of polynomials, the matrix will have to differentiate $n$ different elements...

Comment: But $\lambda$ must differentiate $f$, correct? if $C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$, how can I have a finite amount of eigenvectors for $D$

Comment: Ok, I'm glad we clarified that $\lambda$ is not a matrix differentiating $f$. I still don't see what I can multiply with $f$ that will give me $f'$ unless I make that matrix I talked about that differentiates the functions. Do you have an example of an eigenvalue with it's corresponding eigenvectors? Maybe that'll hit a lightbulb in my head.I feel like I'm complicating the matter too much at this point

Comment: @novo If it's ok with you, I will just upgrade my hint to an answer and delete the above clutter.

Comment: I think I get it now, but just to make sure: I think I was too hung up on finding $\lambda$ that satifies all $f'=\lambda * f$. But you've found what $f$ has to be in order for us to be able to write $f' = \lambda *f$. So $f$ has to be on the form $c*e^{\lambda x}$ for the functions to have an eigenvalue and eigenvectors? Is that the correct interpretation? I appreciate your guidance very much and don't understand the downvotes. I will of course accept your answer.

Comment: Thats exactly correct. Maybe it would help to think about initially fixing $\lambda$ and finding $f$ which satisfy the eigenvalue equation. If they exist, you have found an eigenvalue by finding an eigenvector. I am happy to help, I just find this site very frustrating at times.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the kernel is the set of constant functions, and yes, there are infinitely may such functions, but they are not linearly independent.

Any nonzero constant function generates all the other constant functions, so take any one of them, and you get a basis.

As regards the eigenvalues of $D$, note that if $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$, and $f(x)=e^{\lambda x}$, then $D(f)=\lambda f$.

Comment: What an odd incentive structure here at mathstackexchange. I address all of OP's questions before this answer, answer a series of questions posed by the OP well beyond a hint in the comments, and still get net zero downvotes while this answer has 1. Any, +1, why not.

Comment: @qbert: Hmmm . . . I posted my answer before looking at the comments, but yes, I agree, you deserve credit as well, so +1.